# Basic loop for using (javascript) with condition

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement

need your help for my problem.
Let say I have an object and an array as my list on my javascript as below:

```js
     var hotel={  "electronic":[
      {  "id":1,
      "tv":"LG"},
    {  "id":2,
      "tv":"Polytron"},
    {  "id":3,
      "tv":"Panasonic"},
    {  "id":4,
      "tv":"Sony"},
      ]
    }
    var mylist=[1,2,1,4,2,3,2,4];
    var mytran;
    var i=0;  
    
    while(i<mylist.length){
    if(mylist[i]===1){
    mytran=hotel.electronic[0].tv;
    }
    else if(mylist[i]===2){
    mytran=hotel.electronic[1].tv;
    }
    else if(mylist[i]===3){
    mytran=hotel.electronic[2].tv;
    }
    else if(mylist[i]===4){
    mytran=hotel.electronic[3].tv;
    }
    console.log(mytran);
    i++;
    }
```

The above code is working, but actually I get the object data from my db which is only have 4 object inside array 'electronic'. My concern is how if I have hundreds object on my electronic data array. It will be have hundreds of if else as well. Do you think we still can to optimize my code? Please your explaination.

Comment: Remove if else and add clear pattern here `mytran=hotel.electronic[i-1].tv;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do something like this:

```
mytran=hotel.electronic[mylist[i]-1].tv;
```

i.e. take the value of mylist[i] as the index

Comment: Good, I think this is the more simple basic that I have to understand.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your loop could be replaced with something like

```
mylist.forEach(function(i) {
    console.log(hotel.electronic[i - 1].tv);
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is very very simple using for each that I never know before. I think this would be optimal than using while loop. Thank you